# Formalised logic equivalent of self fulfilling prophecy?

Tags: logic

For example

> Will this query be answered correctly?
>
> *Yes*
>
> Has this query been answered correctly?

A.

> Yes, therefore "yes" is the correct answer, therefore this query has
>   been answered correctly.

B.

> No, therefore "no" is the correct answer, therefore this query has
>   been answered incorrectly.

Either assumption is verified.

What is the technical term for this phenomenon, and what formalised studies exist on it? The closest I can find is the informal concept of "self fulfilling prophecy."

Comment: This is called use-reference (http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reference/). You can't formalize it in garden variety logic.

Comment: What are you talking about in the example are self referential statements, not self fulfilling prophecies. Please change your question accordingly.

Comment: If you want to get intense, see [Diagonalization and Self-Reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=diagonalization+and+self+reference).

Comment: Check out Löb's theorem: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Löb's_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you condense each question-answer pair into one completed proposition, you get self-referential statements such as P = "P is true". Aside from the trickiness associated with such statements, you're not so much arguing about the correctness of P, but the *internal consistency* of the correctness or incorrectness of P, which in each case  is an example of circular reasoning.